# Is it OK to send cookie headers directly with "header()" calls?

Tags: php, cookies, header, http-headers

Is it OK to send cookie headers directly with [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) calls?

I am tinkering with http cookie mechanism in PHP and would like (at least initially) to try the "raw" thing :)

The [Brad Christie's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298053/brad-christie) answer to ["php-how-to-stringify-array-and-store-in-cookie"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672130/php-how-to-stringify-array-and-store-in-cookie) assumes it is, but is there a somehow official source on the topic (or is it at least a well-known practice)?

Thanks in advance for clarifying the topic.

**[EDIT: AN IMPORTANT NOTICE]**

An interesting thing I have discovered is that calling `header('Set-Cookie: ...');` effectively prevents any cookies previously supplied with `setcookie('...');` from being sent, at least on my machine (PHP 5.3.5, Apache 2.2.17, WinXP SP2). Whether this is a feature / bug(?) or a consequence of PHP semantics/rules violation, I don't know.

Analyzing PHP `.c` sources will possibly bring an answer (one should posibly look into `head.c` (`header()`, `setcookie()`, etc) and `mod_php5.c` (Apache module) files for that).

Comment: It probably goes against German laws.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario How so? Too strict?

Comment: Side question: is there a real cookie spec at last?

Comment: @Alvaro I would say RFC 2965 is the "spec" -- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt

Comment: @mlvljr The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) says that by default, a call to this function will replace any previous header with the same name. This might be the reason why it overrides any previous value set with `setcookie()`. Have you tried with `header('Set-Cookie: ...', false);`?

Comment: @Benjamin May be (but more probably, not), can't remember for sure; I do remember being pissed off by PHP behaving in a surprizingly unintuitive manner, but may be I just got unlucky, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IT IS NOT**

Please see the "edit" part of the question.

Comment: ...but also see recent @Benjamin 's comment to the question

Answer (score 4):

Considering cookies are just HTTP headers, you can, of course, send them using the **`header()`** function.

But this is re-inventing the wheel (and you'll have to deal with all possibilities yourself), as PHP provides the [**`setcookie()`**](http://fr.php.net/setcookie) function.

Still, if you want to learn how cookies work, why not ? 

This can be interesting ;-)

Comment: So, the practice is totally OK -- no extra processing by PHP, etc? (I just remember that sending a response header is recognized as such and processed in a special (appropriate) way)

Comment: Using `header()` to set up cookies in a real application doesn't look like a good idea, considering there is `setcookie()` ; but, as a learning exercice, yes, it's totally OK to re-invent the wheel ;-)

Answer (score 2):

PHP won't care either way. Setting a cookie just means sending the header. There's nothing else involved from PHP's site (unless you're talking about sessions, but apparently you aren't). You can send any raw header you want, PHP won't care. If you send the correct header and the client returns the cookie on the next request, PHP will parse it correctly into the `$_COOKIE` array. And that's all there is to it.

Comment: is it documented somewhere (yes, i'm almost sure it isn't but anyway)?
or i should just look at the PHP sources to get (final) confidence?

Comment: @mlv [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) says there are two special cases for header: `Location:` and `HTTP/` headers. All other headers are just output as given without side effects. I'm afraid this kind of negative confirmation is the best you'll find. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely ok. There is no difference between proper cookies sent with raw headers and ones sent via `set_cookie()`.

Comment: Seems there are more intricacies than we have thought there are, I've updated my question.