# Storing arrays in cookies

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I need to store some array data in a cookie and I have been researching the best way to do it, many people seem to say using `serialize` is the way to go, but then in this thread:

[PHP how to stringify array and store in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672130/php-how-to-stringify-array-and-store-in-cookie)

..someone suggested against using it as "serialize will call constructor of a serialized class. This is bad because it can cause code execution."

So I'm wondering what other options I have? What about `base64_encode`?

I can't use `sessions` as I need to retain the data AFTER the browser is closed; though I am also worried about Cookies `4KB` limit.

FWIW I am storing shopping cart data of what is stored in someones cart, it needs to be loaded back in their cart when they come back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about generating a unique ID, storing it in a cookie, and storing your serialized array and the ID in database?

Example:

```
// ------------ STORING TO COOKIE AND DATABASE ------------ //
$id = uniqid();
setcookie("id", $id, time()+60*60*24); // 1 day

$serialized = serialize($array);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO yourTable (id, array) VALUES ('$id', '$serialized')");


// ------------ SELECTING FROM DATABASE ------------ //
if(!isset($_COOKIE['id'])) die();
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['id']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT array FROM yourTable WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1");
if(!is_resource($result)) die();
$serialized = mysql_result($result, 0);
$array = unserialize($serialized);
```

Comment: +1 , seems to be the best solution as it's highly advisable not to use cookies to store things other than identification or minor settings.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on previous comments and answrs, you should try really hard to avoid **data** being stored in a cookie, as opposed to **a pointer to data**, such as an ID to a database row.

Assuming, that all clients are enemies (which I think to be reasonable assumption), a wrong cookie - be it malicious or simply buggy - will be unable to do much harm, if it only contains a pointer:

- Invalid: Silently drop it
- Wrong: Check by comparing ID to the user, who is requesting it; Silently drop it if so
- Valid; use it

I peronally prefer silent dropping to error messages, as I have the gut feeling, that this might make it harder for the very few really malicious users out there.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie it is not best way store user data
Users must be authorized on your site, and all data must be stored in database by user_id